# Hide a specific legend only from FusionChart

Tags: javascript, legend, fusioncharts

How to hide a specific legend from multi-series fusionChart. Actually I want to remove a specific series from chart, when exporting I need to show that on excel sheet. So my plan is initial time hide from the chart then remove that legend from legend section.

I have used `'initiallyhidden' => 1,` property, that time it will not shown in the chart. Now I want to remove that series name from legend also.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oL2u3vbd/1/

Comment: With a fusionChart time series chart I manipulated visibility of data and legends by dynamically adjusting the schema of the chart object. I think if you're trying to remove a whole series (say Q1) you could just dynamically manipulate the categories property. The data would still be there it would just be a matter of re-including that category on export. Am I understanding your question?

Comment: @RyanRau - Yeah, right... I don't want to show a series on chart... But when I'm exporting, that time I want to include it on excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the categories within the datasource and dynamically change the chart's datasource when readying to export to excel. You just have to make sure to revert the change so it doesn't affect the visible chart.

```js
document.getElementById("export").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // december 2013 isn't shown but is included in excel export
  let oldDataCategories = [...fusionData.dataSource.categories[0].category]
  
  // Add Dec back to the categories && export
  fusionData.dataSource.categories[0].category.push({ label: "Dec 2013" });
  FusionCharts("myChartId").setChartData(fusionData.dataSource, 'json');
  FusionCharts("myChartId").exportChart({ exportFormat: "csv" })
  
  //revert categories back
  fusionData.dataSource.categories[0].category = oldDataCategories;
  console.log(fusionData.dataSource.categories[0].category)
  FusionCharts("myChartId").setChartData(fusionData.dataSource, 'json');
});
```

Here is a example, You'll see there's not series for `Dec. 2013` on the chart but when you export it that data is included.

https://jsfiddle.net/xv3ps9b5/3/